# Get list of vertices of regular polygon

Tags: java, geometry

I have a regular polygon defined by the x and y coordinate of the center, the number of sides, the side length, and the rotation from the horizontal. It's consistently spitting out zero for every coordinate. Here's the code:

```
public Point[] getPoints() {
    Point[] points = new Point[n];
    double radius = s/(2*Math.sin(Math.PI/n));
    double angle = (Math.PI*2)/n;
    points[0] = new Point((int)Math.round(r),0);
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        points[i] = multiplyByRotationMatrix(points[i-1],angle);
        System.out.println(points[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        points[i].x += x;
        points[i].y += y;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        points[i] = multiplyByRotationMatrix(points[i],r);
    }
    return points;
}

private Point multiplyByRotationMatrix(Point p, double angle) {
    if(angle==0) return p;
    Point2D pNew = new Point2D.Float();
    pNew = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(angle,p.x,p.y).transform(p, pNew);
    System.out.println(pNew.toString() + " , " + p.x + "," + p.y);
    return new Point((int)Math.round(pNew.getX()),(int)Math.round(pNew.getY()));
}
```

The rotation matrix bit was actually a rotation matrix at some point, but I changed it to AffineTransform to see if it would work (It didn't). What is a better way to go about this?

Comment: It seems that the value of the elements of `points` is from the variables `x` and `y`. What are their values? Where are they defined?

Comment: `x` and `y` are instantiated in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(angle,p.x,p.y)` creates matrix that rotates point `p` around **itself**, so its position does not change.

You approach assumes that rotation should be made about origin, so you can use one-argument version of `getRotateInstance`.

Note that you can create rotation matrix once and reuse it inside the cycle.

In my opinion, generation of points at circumference in a single cycle is simpler a bit:

```
 p[i].x = center_x + radius * Cos(rotation_shift + i * 2 * Pi / n) 
 the same for y with Sin
```